# how to use ng-click to perform 2 different action on consecutive clicks?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

in my angular app I got a popover with dropdown list, and 3 buttons for each element of the list (the third is not shown in the pic).
I have implemented that when you click on a button it changes the background, as you can see here:

[image]

the code for it is pretty simple:

controller:

```
this.selectedButtons = 'unconfirmed';


setButton(buttonState: string) {
        this.selectedButtons = buttonState;
    }

isButton(buttonState: string) {
        return buttonState === this.selectedButtons;
    }
```

view:

```
ng-click="vm.setButton('declined')"

ng-class="{'Default' : vm.isButton('unconfirmed'), 'Confirmed' : vm.isButton('confirmed'), 'Declined' : vm.isButton('declined'), 'Deleted' : vm.isButton('deleted')}"
```

so pretty simple, when I click on one of the buttons, it will set the var to one of the strings, and then with ng-class I call the class equal to that string.

Work as intended, but I have a problem, I want also when you click on the same button again, it "undo" your selection, so returning to "default" class.

I understand how to do this with something like: `ng-click= test= !test`
so when you click it again it goes back to the initial state, but here I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: `if(this.selectedButtons == buttonState) { this.selectedButtons = null; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code provided, if you want to 'undo' then you should check if the button is in the changed state and change it back if so:

```
this.selectedButtons = 'unconfirmed';


setButton(buttonState: string) {
        if (this.selectedButtons == buttonState) {
            this.selectedButtons = 'unconfirmed';
        }
        else {
            this.selectedButtons = buttonState;
        }
    }

isButton(buttonState: string) {
        return buttonState === this.selectedButtons;
    }
```

Comment: works perfectly, don't know why I didnt come up with it, seems so logic! thank you